# query to find all dblink()

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Besides manually searching for all the dblink() used in triggers/functions/stored procedures is there a way to query for this information?

Example: There is a dblink inside of a trigger, can I select something from the postgres schema that would identify this?

I'm thinking this is a manual effort but asking just to make sure I'm not missing something.

NOTE: I have some logging where I am also looking for dblink()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would draw a text backup and search it with `vim` or any tool of your choice.

As far as plpgsql functions are concerned (there is one behind every trigger), you can query the system catalog [`pg_proc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-proc.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
WHERE  prosrc ILIKE '%dblink%';
```

Comment: Thanks a combination of grep and this helped my efforts!

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from information_schema._pg_foreign_servers;
```

OR

```
select * from pg_foreign_server;
```

Comment: Foreign servers are something different than dblink() calls

Comment: Although @a_horse_with_no_name is technically correct, this information was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all open `dblink` connections using [`dblink_get_connections()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/contrib-dblink-get-connections.html).

Those that are not used can only be found by examining your function code like [Erwin suggests](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93603/6219).  I thought that with SQL functions one can query for the `dblink` functions it depends on, but it happens not to be the case (actually, you can even drop the extension while having functions using `dblink_connect()`, for example.)

Comment: Objects used in the function body of a plpgsql function do not get dependency entries in `pg_depend` (like it happens when a view references a table). So these dependencies are not enforced by the system.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, that was clear, but what I saw was that even SQL functions don't observe the dependency on the `dblink` extension's functions...